# Как объединить два ArrayList<String> в один новый?

Tags: java, android, список

Как объединить два ArrayList в один новый?

Раньше использовал обычный `String[]`, и функция выглядела так, но как поступить сейчас?

```
public static String[] ArrayAndArrayNewArray(String[] a, String[] b) {
    if (a == null)
        return b;
    if (b == null)
        return a;
    String[] r = new String[a.length + b.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, r, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, r, a.length, b.length);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: У вас не  ArrayList, а массивы(array). Вам действительно необходимо объединить два  ArrayList'а, или все-таки 2 массива?

Comment: @NektoDev: ну два массива он вроде бы уже умеет. Представленный код как раз это и делает.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### 1. Без проверки на `null`

Вот достаточно простая и малооптимизированная реализация. Если этот участок не является узким местом в вашем приложении, то дальнейшая оптимизация, вероятно, не нужна. Не сработает, если один из аргументов будет равен `null`. **Можно использовать, только если это внутренний код и вы достоверно знаете, что аргументы определены.**

```
List<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>(listA);
listC.addAll(listB);
```

Должен заметить, что и в **вашей реализации объединения массивов есть существенные уязвимости, связанные с `null`**.

1. Если один из списков `== null`, то метод вернет не новый массив, а один из старых.
2. Если оба списка `== null`, то будет возвращен `null`, что вряд ли ожидаемо

Исправлять ошибки метода для объединения массивов следует в отдельном вопросе, а здесь я приведу код, который устойчив к аргументам со значением `null`.

### 2. Проверяем и молча пропускаем `null`

Метод обобщен согласно [правилу PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2790048).

```
public static <T> ArrayList<? super T> joinLists(
        final List<? extends T> listA,
        final List<? extends T> listB) {

    boolean aEmpty = (listA == null) || listA.isEmpty();
    boolean bEmpty = (listB == null) || listB.isEmpty();
    //побитное И!
    if (aEmpty & bEmpty) {
        // оба пустые — отдаем новый пустой список
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    } else if (aEmpty) {
        // один пустой — отдаем копию другого, содержащую все его элементы
        return new ArrayList<T>(listB);
    } else if (bEmpty) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(listA);
    } else {
        // оба непустые — объединяем
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(
                listA.size() + listB.size());
        result.addAll(listA);
        result.addAll(listB);
        return result;
    }
}
```

### 3. Проверяем `null` и бросаем исключения

```
/**
 * Join two lists and raise an exception if any is null
 *
 * @throws NullPointerException
 *         if any parameter is null
 */
public static <T> List<? super T> joinLists2(
        final List<? extends T> listA,
        final List<? extends T> listB) {

    if (listA == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("listA is null");
    }
    if (listB == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("listB is null");
    }
    if (listA.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(listB);
    } else if (listB.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(listA);
    } else {
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>(
                listA.size() + listB.size());
        result.addAll(listA);
        result.addAll(listB);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList` - это обёртка для обычного массива. Есть счётчик `size`, который считает, сколько элементов массива использовано.
По ходу того, как добавляются новые элементы, `size` увеличивается, а когда весь массив будет заполнен, `ArrayList` выделяет новый массив большей длины и копирует в него все элементы.
Отсюда следует, что наиболее эффективным будет такое заполнение списка, при котором внутренний массив будет достаточной длины, и не будет происходить выделение нового массива.
Для этого, у `ArrayList` есть конструктор с `int` параметром, в котором указывается, на сколько элементов должен быть выделен массив изначально.

```
public static List<String> joinLists(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    if ((a == null) || (a.isEmpty() && (b != null))) return b;
    if ((b == null) || b.isEmpty()) return a;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList(a.size() + b.size()); // Закладываем размер достаточный для всех элементов
    result.addAll(a);
    result.addAll(b);
    return result;
}
```

Но, поскольку `addAll` внутри себя использует неявное создание временного массива, то, если заранее известно, что исходные списки - это `ArrayList`, то большей эффективности по памяти можно достичь следующим образом. Следует учесть, что вариант ниже позволяет избежать выделения лишних массивов и уменьшить затраты на сборку мусора (больная тема в Андроиде, особенно в ранних версиях), но он не обязательно эффективнее по скорости, скорее даже наоборот.

```
public static List<String> joinLists(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
    if ((a == null) || (a.isEmpty() && (b != null))) return b;
    if ((b == null) || b.isEmpty()) return a;
    int aSize = a.size();
    int bSize = b.size();
    // Закладываем размер достаточный для всех элементов
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList(aSize + bSize); 
    // Если списки обеспечивают быстрый доступ к своим элементам, например ArrayList
    if ((a instanceof RandomAccess) && (b instanceof RandomAccess)) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) result.add(a.get(i));
        for (int i = 0; i < bSize; i++) result.add(b.get(i));
    } else { 
    // А если это какие-то крестьянские списки, то копируем по-крестьянски 
        result.addAll(a);
        result.addAll(b);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, в первом примере на первых строчках предполагалось копирование a и b в новый ArrayList, т.к. иначе изменения результирующего списка будут по понятным причинам синхронно появляться и в списке-аргументы, что для вызывающего кода может оказаться неожиданным.

Comment: @Etki, да. Но с массивами в вопросе делается так же. Хотя не для случая с пустым массивом.

Comment: @Etki: а еще, если оба `null`, то будет возвращен `null`.

Comment: чуть поправил, чтобы каноничнее было